# How to pass parameter to new created view via DI

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm pretty new to PRISM and I have to say, every day I love it more and more! Currently, I'm struggling with a problem how to pass a parameter to newly created view (via Dependency Injection). My situation is as follows:
user clicks on a button and a new view is created on the right side of the screen. I'm doing this, as follows:

IRegion region = this._regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ActionRegion];

```
 object boxView = region.GetView("BoxDetailsView");
 if (boxView == null)
        {
       boxView = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BoxDetailsView>();
            region.Add(boxView, "BoxDetailsView");
        }

        region.Activate(boxView);
```

This works pretty fine. However, I do need to pass a parameter to that view and I don't have a clue how. OnNavigationFrom & OnNaviagationTo does not work, as I'm not navigating from the MainView, I'm just opening additional view.
I did check the very famous Stock Trader RI, however, I didn't still find a way to accomplish it.

I feel like I'm very close but doing some little thing wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the navigation framework.  Just use RequestNavigate and pass parameters with the method call.  Then have your View/ViewModel implement INavigationAware and then you'll have access to the parameters you passed.

Answer (score 0):

Im new in prism too, but in my project I used RegionContext to pass parameter as viewmodel to child view. (I used Unity to resolve view)

region in xaml ([source](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.MainModule/ServerInfoControl.xaml#L37)):

```
    <TabControl 
    regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ServerTabPartRegion}" 
    regions:RegionManager.RegionContext="{Binding CurrentServer, Mode=OneWay}">
    </TabControl>
```

View registration ([source](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.OnlinePlayersModule/OnlinePlayersModuleInit.cs#L30))

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ServerTabPartRegion, CreateView);
    }

    private object CreateView()
    {
        return ServerTabViewHelper.RegisterView<OnlinePlayers, ServerInfo, ServerMonitorPlayerViewModel>(_container,
            "serverInfo");
    }
```

Helper to get parameter ([source](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Infrastructure/Helpers/ServerTabViewHelper.cs))

```
public static class ServerTabViewHelper
{
    public static TView RegisterView<TView, TViewParameter, TViewModel>(IUnityContainer container, string parameterName)
        where TView : FrameworkElement where TViewParameter : class
    {
        var view = container.Resolve<TView>();
        var context = RegionContext.GetObservableContext(view);
        context.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            var obs = s as ObservableObject<object>;
            if (obs != null)
            {
                var serverInfo = obs.Value as TViewParameter;
                var vm = container.Resolve<TViewModel>(new ParameterOverride(parameterName, serverInfo));
                view.DataContext = vm;
            }
        };
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the view model upon navigation has the advantage that the view model is always in initialized state (provided you have all data available when navigating to prevent delays).

To do it with prism, though, you have to use a modified `RegionNavigationService`, as the functionality won't be included in the framework (as of now, see [this issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/367))...

Extend the `ExecuteNavigation` method:

```
[...update journal...]

// Create and set the view model based on the navigation context
var viewAsDependencyObject = view as DependencyObject;
if (viewAsDependencyObject != null)
{
    var createViewModelOnNavigateTo = ViewModelLocator.GetCreateViewModelOnNavigateTo( viewAsDependencyObject );
    if (createViewModelOnNavigateTo)
        ViewModelLocator.Bind( view, _viewModelProvider.CreateViewModel( viewAsDependencyObject, navigationContext ) );
}

[...inform view...]
```

Other changes include:

- `_viewModelProvider` : a service similar to the `ViewModelLocator` that creates viewmodels from the `NavigationContext`
- `CreateViewModelOnNavigate` : an attached property similar to `AutoWireViewModel` to mark the view that it should receive a newly created view model when navigating to it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for suggestions and hints! I do really appreciate it! I think Brian's suggestion is the easiest and I solved it that way:

IRegion region = this._regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ActionRegion];

```
        object boxView = region.GetView("BoxDetailsView");
        if (boxView == null)
        {
            boxView = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BoxDetailsView>();
            region.Add(boxView, "BoxDetailsView");
            // Navigate to view
            var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
            parameters.Add("BOXID", param);
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ActionRegion, new Uri("BoxDetailsView" + parameters, UriKind.Relative));

        }
```